# how to find same numbers in a list if they are sequential?

Tags: python, list

Firstly sorry for my english.I will try to explain my situation.

I have a list and contains numbers as [0...255]. Im trinyg to find numbers in list like this.

[0,7,**3,3**,55,12...] as you can see numbers 3 same and sequential. I want to find only them not like this [0,7,*3,5,3*,55,12...]. In this list, there are same numbers but not sequential. I want to add that code to my below code.

```
    if color in images[:-1]:
    print("Eşi bulundu",*cards[images.index(color )],"ile",*cards[len(images)-1])
    if i%2==0:
        esClick(*cards[images.index(color )])
        time.sleep(2)
        #esClick(*cards[len(images)-1])
        #time.sleep(2)
    images.insert(images.index(color ), 256)
    images.pop(images.index(color ))
    images.pop()
    images.append(256)
    print(images)
```

I couldnt figure out how to code for this

How can i implement this ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: See itertools.groupby

Comment: @DaniMesejo thanks for idea, is there an easy way ? Im new on programming and it looks hard for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

I think the easy way is to just iterate over the list and check whether you can find the same numbers or not.

```
for i in range(len(array)-1):
   if array[i] == array[i+1]:
       print(array[i]) // or add it to another list
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code prints a list with (index, index+1, number):

```
a = [0, 0, 7, 3, 3, 7 ,55, 0, 12, 12]
ans = [(i-1, i, x) for i, x in enumerate(a) if x==a[i-1] and i>0]
print(ans)  # --> [(0, 1, 0), (3, 4, 3), (8, 9, 12)]
```